# Get Gson Key's Name In An Overriden Adapter

Tags: java, json, scala, gson

I have overriden an Integer Adapter in GSON to parse my JSON. Reason for doing this is that the GSON method `parseJson` simply throws the `JsonSyntaxException` if anything goes wrong. To avoid sending a generic exception I created this adapter. I want the adapter to throw an exception along with the name of the Key. Problem is that I can not get the key name in the overriden method `deserialize` of `JsonDeserializer[T]`

Code snippet

```
val integerAdapter = new JsonDeserializer[Integer] {
override def deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Integer = {

  Try(json.getAsInt) //JsonElement object has only the value
  match {
    case Success(value) => value
    case Failure(ex) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex) // here i want the name of the key to be thrown in the exception and manage accordingly

  }
 }
}
```

Json:`{
  "supplierId":"21312",
  "isClose":false,
  "currency":"USD",
  "statusKey":1001,
  "statusValue":"Opened ",
  "statusDateTime":"2014-03-10T18:46:40.000Z",
  "productKey":2001,
  "productValue":"Trip Cancellation",
  "TypeKey":3001,
  "TypeValue":"Trip Cancellation",
  "SubmitChannelKey":4001,
  "SubmitChannelValue":"Web asdsad",
  "tripNumber":"01239231912",
  "ExpiryDateTime":"2014-03-10T18:46:40.000Z",
  "numberOfants":4,
  "AmountReserved":901232,
  "AmountRequested":91232
}`

Any leads on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter is a deserializer for the Integer type which is a wrapper for a primitive. Because it's not a regular object, Gson will not associate a key with it.

Why not implement a deserializer for the whole JSON object to have access to all keys?

```
class MyObject {
    private Integer supplierId;
    private boolean isClose;
    // TODO: the other fields in the JSON string
}

class MyObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {

    public MyObject deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        // TODO: construct a new MyObject instance
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid any manual getter setter in my codebase. I feel there is no other way out. I think even with Jackson i would have to create a deserializer for the whole Object

Comment: The keys of the JSON string are mapped to the field names of the object you're trying to deserialize and therefore can't be accessed in any other way within the deserializer than when implementing one for the whole object.

Comment: I just don't understand why **JsonDeserializationContext** literally has _no context_! There are zero getters to query about current state. `JsonDeserializationContext.getKey()` is sorely needed.